# Add a Controller class to a Servlet using Jersey Annotation getting 404

Tags: java, spring, jersey

In the web.xml is defined this servlet mapping:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS External REST Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>xxx.rest.external.XxxExternalRestApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.DisableWADL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS External REST Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/external/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I cannot modify the web.xml.

I have created a `WebAppplicationInitializer` in order to get the registered Servlet on the path `/external/rest`
Here is the code:

```
package com.xxx.extended.base.config.sailpoint;

import com.xxx.extended.controllers.IRestControllerMarker;
import com.xxx.extended.controllers.LocalManagedEntitlementsRestController;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletProperties;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

/**
 * Uses to extend parameter of external rest api to include custom controllers
 */
public class XxxExternalRestWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer
{
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(XxxExternalRestWebApplicationInitializer.class);
    /**
     * Rest api servlet name
     */
    private static final String REST_SERVLET_NAME = "JAX-RS External REST Servlet";


    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        log.debug("Try to get external servlet by name:[{}]", REST_SERVLET_NAME);



        var registration = servletContext.getServletRegistration(REST_SERVLET_NAME);

        if (registration == null) {
            log.error("Could not find external servlet registration. External api will not work!!!!");
            return;
        }

        registration.setInitParameter(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, LocalManagedEntitlementsRestController.class.getPackageName());

        log.debug("Registered the controllers from this package: [{}]",IRestControllerMarker.class.getPackage().getName());

    }
}
```

After the startup of the application the `WebApplicationInitializer` is actually recognized, but when I am sending a GET request to the controller I get a 404 Not Found, I pretty sure the URL is fine.

Actually it seems not scanning the package to fetch the controllers to show.
My feeling is that because in the Application defined:
`xxx.rest.external.XxxExternalRestApplication`
the controllers class are registed sigularly, it is not going scan packages.

Here the simplified code of the controller I'm trying to use:

```
@Path("custom")
public class LocalManagedEntitlementsRestController extends BaseResource
{
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(LocalManagedEntitlementsRestController.class);

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    public String sayHello()
    {
        return "Welcome to the world of REST";
    }
}
```

Comment: You registered the servlet, but no mappings, so no URL will be mapped to the servlet. You say *"registered Servlet on the path `/external/rest`"*, but that path is nowhere to be found in the code.

Comment: It is in the Web.xml:
`    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JAX-RS External REST Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/external/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`

Comment: Now I'm really confused. What are you trying to do here? Are you really trying to *replace* the `XxxExternalRestApplication` class with the `SixExternalRestApplication` class? If so, why does your title say "add", not "replace"?

Comment: Absolutely not, just adding my controller to the already defined Application:
xxx.rest.external.XxxExternalRestApplication

Comment: But `setInitParameter()` ***replaces*** the value of the `javax.ws.rs.Application` parameter. Besides, your class is not even an "Application" class, is it?

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake in one of the tentatives, now I have corrected it, I'm only setting the packages to scan actually

Comment: What is the purpose of using the WebApplicationInitializer (besides setting the init-param, which could be done in the web.xml)?

Comment: The web.xml is from aproduct and we would like to not modify it actually. I'm just trying to make my controllers' package to be scanned

Comment: Do it in the `XxxExternalRestApplication` class. Just call the `packages()` method in the constructor.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha, sorry. I cannot change that class because actially it is a standard one

Comment: I am not completely sure, but it's possible the init-param is not set in time (just a guess). You can try to [create an AutoDiscoverable](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.autodiscoverable) and use the `property()` method to set the scanning property. Make sure you create the META-INF/services file ([for example](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/tree/master/media/json-jackson/src/main/resources/META-INF/services)).

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I'm trying, but I could set the property only for that specific servlet?